# Extending to a continuous function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, continuity

Le a function f will be given for all pairs of real numbers $(x, y)$, where $y > 0$,
by the formula $f(x, y) = e^{\frac{x^2}{y}}$. Check whether f can extend to a continuous function on the set:

$(a)\ \{(x, y): y  \ge ­ 0, x  \in  R, (x, y)  \neq  (0, 0)\};
$

$(b)\ \{(x, y): y  \ge ­ 0, x  \in  R\}.$

My attepmt was to set $x_0$ i check if a limit exists $\lim_{(x,y)\to(x_0,0)} f(x,y)$. If not, there is no extension else  this limit is a candidat on $f(x_0,0)$ (I calculated and received $\infty$).

But it seems to be a bad solution...

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially done. In fact  you can fix $x$ to be $x_0=1$.

When $x=1$,$\lim_{y \to 0+} e^{\frac {x^{2}} y}=\infty$, so  the answer is NO in both cases.